# Kamailio 5.0.* how should I get the private ip address if I know the UAC is behind one or more NAT?

Tags: nat, kamailio

Is it different in case of INVITE or REGISTER messages and UDP,TCP,TLS transport?
There is a nathelper module that allows to test if the UAC is behind  NAT with function     nat_uac_test() help. But it is not clear ho to use it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

If the UAC is behind the NAT and the NAT router does not act as SIP ALG (it does not change the content of SIP traffic), then the private IP address of UAC should be in Contact header address and in the last Via header. You can get the Contact header address with:

```
$(ct{tobody.host})
```

The address of the last Via header should be:

```
$sel(via[-1].host)
```

In the INVITE, the private IP of UAC should be in SDP body as well.